# Why does HTML 5 Audio disregards mobile device audio settings such as silent or volume?

Tags: javascript, mobile, html5-audio

I have a site that targets mobile android users. I’m using the HTML5 audio to play background music.

The audio is played even if the device is on silent; also the audio is played in the highest volume regardless of the device volume settings.

Does anyone know why these things happen or how to get the device current audio settings?
I’d prefer a client side (javascript) solution but I’m open to all solution.

Thank you for your help
Moshe S.

Comment: with phonegap you can get the volume of device .set it to browser volume.

Comment: @ArunKillu I believe the reverse is desired - _read_ the device settings.

Comment: Anyways, this seems to be a browser bug. The browser should mute _any_ audio if the phone is on silent.

Comment: @JanDvorak i ment that only ,came out like that

Comment: with phonegap you can get the volume of device .set browser volume to that

Comment: Uhh, as far as I can tell, your media volume, and ringer volume are different. Try playing a song locally, and even that'll probably play on the same volume.

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for the quick responses. 
I have tried my web site on IPhone and the same problem happens.  With IPhone I had to add a click event for the audio to play.
The audio played regardless the device settings. 
Any other thoughts?
Keep in mind this is a web site and not a web app, so I’m sure how much phoneGap helps here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android, even if the phone is on silent, the media volume will not change.

I'm not sure if android allows for the modification of the system sound settings through the browser, since the default one does not have permission to change/read the volume state.

Comment: Yes. Android has a separate volume settings for media and ringtone style audio. You can configure separately this through Android settings, it's not a bug, it's feature. And the way Android do is very difficult to grasp even for advanced users, so it is mostly shitty Android user experience we can blame here.