# Don't play HTML5 audio when vibrate switch is on

Tags: iphone, ios, html, audio

I've writing a little web app that will target iPhone initially. One of it's functions is to play an audio file when an icon is clicked. I do this with the following code:

```
$('#quickSample').click( function() { $('#theSound').get(0).play(); });
```

Then the relevant HTML is:

```
<audio id="theSound" src="demo.mp3"></audio>

<div class="icon">
  <a href="" id="quickSample" title="Quick Sample">
    <i class="icon-volume-up icon-2x"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that it plays this audio file even when the iPhone is switched to silent or vibrate mode. I want to be nice and NOT play the sound when the phone is in vibrate mode. Can I test for vibrate mode and skip playing if it's on? Is there a better way?  I actually expected this to be default behavior.

Comment: easy answer no, using phonegap, yes

Comment: take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110508/why-does-html-5-audio-disregards-mobile-device-audio-settings-such-as-silent-or